# Mocking a promise returning method from the same class

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to mock/stub the resolve of a class method that returns a promise when testing another method of the same class. I'm using `jest`.

I have the following class `Blah` of which I want to test the `foo()` method:

```
export default class Blah {
  foo () {
    this.bar().then(result => {
      // some logic here
    })
  }

  bar () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      // fetches some stuff over the network
      resolve('hello world')
    })
  }
}
```

Because `foo()` uses `bar()` - a promise returning method that does stuff over the network - I would like to mock the resolve of `bar()`; let's say make it resolve `what up`.

Let's say the test would look something like this:

```
import Blah from './blah'

test('foo() - bar() resolves "what up"', () => {
  const blah = new Blah()
  // mock blah.bar() so that is resolves "what up"

  // {some assertions on blah.foo() here}
})
```

It's my first time working with `jest` and I've read through the docs, but I'm still having a hard time wrapping my head around this case.

How can I mock the resolved value of `bar()` while testing `foo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still just JavaScript meaning *any* object property can be dynamically overwritten:

```
// in the test file
const blah = new Blah();
blah.bar = _ => Promise.resolve("what up");

// now some assertions about blah.foo
```

Comment: thanks, if you'll pardon my ignorance, why the `_` in this context?

Comment: @Juicy it's a fairly common convention for "I don't care what arguments are passed to this function". The underscore (and dollar sign) are valid JavaScript identifiers. I could have written `blah.bar = dontcare => Promise.resolve...` just force of habit :)